# Анимация jQuery

Tags: jquery

Скажите, как сделать, чтобы `jQuery.animate` работал со свойствами типа
 `-webkit-filter: brightness() blur();` где параметр не в виде параметр: значение

Comment: А в каком тогда виде? Разве "`-webkit-filter`" — это не параметр, а "`brightness() blur()`" — это не значение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Действительно, jQuery.animate не работает с такими значениями. Но в этом нет ничего плохого, потому что css3 уже содержит нужный функционал. [Так](http://jsfiddle.net/kazatca/CfHK6/) можно обойтись вообще без js.